# python regex pattern to extract value between two characters

Tags: python, regex, url

I am trying to extract an id number from urls in the form of

```
http://www.domain.com/some-slug-here/person/237570
http://www.domain.com/person/237570
```

either one of these urls could also have params on them

```
http://www.domain.com/some-slug-here/person/237570?q=some+search+string
http://www.domain.com/person/237570?q=some+search+string
```

I have tried the following expressions to capture the id value of '237570' from the above urls but each one kinda works but does work across all four url scenarios.

```
(?<=person\/)(.*)(?=\?)
(?<=person\/)(.*)(?=\?|\z)
(?<=person\/)(.*)(?=\??*)
```

what I am seeing happening is it is getting the 237570 but including the ? and characters that come after it in the url. how can I say stop capturing either when you hit a ?, /, or the end of the string?

Comment: thanks d3t0n4t0 and m.buettner - i should've included that the ids can be alphanumeric such as /person/35004902B839ABA2 I changed the `(.*)` to `(\w{1,})` and it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String:

```
http://www.domain.com/some-slug-here/person/1234?q=some+search+string
http://www.domain.com/person/3456?q=some+search+string
http://www.domain.com/some-slug-here/person/5678
http://www.domain.com/person/7890
```

Regexp:

```
person\/(\d{1,})
```

Output:

```
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'1234', u'3456', u'5678', u'7890']
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.*` to match the ID. `.` will match any character (except for line breaks, unless you use the DOTALL option). Just match a bunch of digits: `(.*)` --> `(\d+)`

Comment: ..or the greedy, perhaps: `(.*?)`

Comment: yes, that should work, too. but I find it not really elegant to match a number with `.*`. One should keep the regex as constrained as possible to avoid unexpected special cases. Of course, you could still add the ungreedy `?` to the digit-version, but it's not necessary any more.

Comment: Agreed. I was just thinking wider, ignoring the numeric requirement. Thanks for the correction btw. I don't know why I wrote greedy instead of ungreedy :)